# scope value in ng-style

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to change the font color in an input field depending on the value in that field.
Ng-style does not "see" the value of the scope. Thus the color doesn't change.

The code I used:

```
<input disabled name="saldo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="saldo" ng-style="{'color': {{saldo}} < 0.00 ? 'red' : 'green') }">
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '<' not a primary expression at column 12 of the expression [{'color':  < 0.00 ? 'red' : 'green') }] starting at [< 0.00 ? 'red' : 'green') }].
```

So how can I get my 'saldo' value in the ng-style? (placing {{saldo}} outside the ng-style, gives the correct value)

Comment: I see you asked a lot of question without marking one as right. Please mark the right answer in your questions. I would help other users and its how Stackoverflow works.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend doing this,

```
<input disabled name="saldo" type="text" class="form-control" 
       placeholder="0.00" ng-model="saldo" 
       ng-style="saldo < 0.00 ? {'color':'red'} : {'color':'green'}">
```

Hope this helps ..

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You don't need of `{{}}` in `ng-style`.

Replace this:

```
<input disabled name="saldo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="saldo" ng-style="{'color': {{saldo}} < 0.00 ? 'red' : 'green') }">
```

with this

```
<input disabled name="saldo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="saldo" ng-style="{'color': saldo < 0.00 ? 'red' : 'green') }">
```

Comment: Thx, no more error. But the result is allways 'green'. I think it is comparing the string saldo in stead of the value?

Comment: i don't know. In my opinion it's better use `ng-class` like: `ng-class="{'saldo-red' : saldo < 0.00, 'saldo-green': saldo >= '0'}"`. But the correct answer is the @nishi-bangar answer's

Answer (score 0):

This snipped may helps you.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.saldo = 1;
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="GreetingController">
<input disabled name="saldo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="saldo" ng-style="saldo < 0.00 ? {color: 'red'} : {color: 'green'}">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code  to change the font color in an input field depending on the value in that field
`<input disabled name="saldo" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="0.00" ng-model="saldo" ng-style="{'color':saldo}">`